# JIRA and find parents that are closed but with open child elements

Tags: jira, jql

I want to do some JIRA cleaning, where I want to monitor if I have closed a parent, but where it actually still have one or more open child elements. I have a JIRA project with many issue types and several possibilities to link a parent - either via the normal `Epic Link`, but also with `Parent Link` and then as a `Sub-task`.

**What I ideally want, is to get a list of parents that are marked as `Status=Done`, but where it has one or more open "children" - whatever that child `issueType` may be.**

I have tried various methods, but not with the result I want. For example I have tried this:

`project="MyProject" AND issueFunction in subtasksOf("filter=1000") AND resolved is EMPTY`

`filter=1000` contains this:

`project="MyProject" AND issuetype=Epic AND Status=Done`

As far as I can see, then this kind of work, as it returns `Sub-task` elements that are opened, but there are multiple problems in this approach. First of all then it only returns `Sub-task` issue type + it triggers only on Epics + it lists the child elements and not the parents. There are also `Story` issues, that I know also should get triggered by this as they are opened!?

Can anyone give a hint for how this maybe could be solved? I am not sure what kind of extensions we have in place in our JIRA system.